# How add data from NSMutableString into NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsmutablestring

is it an possible to add a value from an `NSMutableString` into an `NSArray`? Whats the snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Mike is wrong. If you want to instantiate an NSArray with a single NSMutableString object, you can do the following:

```
NSMutableString *myString; //Assuming your string is here
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myString];
```

There is no `arrayWithElements` in `NSArray` (see [NSArray documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html))

Comment: Sorry about the typo. My example is fixed, using the `arrayWithObjects` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to instantiate an `NSArray` with a single `NSMutableString` object, you can do the following:

```
NSString *myString; //Assuming your string is here
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myString,nil];
```

Note that NSArray will be immutable - that is, you can't add or remove objects to it after you've made it. If you want the array to be mutable, you'll have to create an `NSMutableArray`. To use an `NSMutableArray` in this fashion, you can do the following:

```
NSString *myString; //Assuming your string is here
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

[NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is immutable, so you cannot add values to it. You should use [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in order to do that with the `addObject:` method.

```
NSMutableString *str = ...
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:str];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You must use NSMutableArray to add Object to array

NSMutableArray *tableCellNames;
// arrayWithCapacity is a required parameter to define limit of your object.
tableCellNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:total_rows];

[tableCellNames addObject:title];
NSLog(@"Array table cell %@",tableCellNames);

//Thanks VKJ
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be this:

```
NSMutableString *str; //your string here
NSArray *newArray = @[str];
```

Using the new notation, it's a piece of cake.